# jQuery function not defined but in console the function works

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I am making a function that checks the query in de url (?regio=zuid). Now the function is not working correctly. 
If I put this in the console

```
jQuery("select[title='Regio']").val(nCorrespondingVal);
```

I get nCorrespondingVal not defined

If I put in the whole function it works correctly

```
    function fnSelectDropDownValue(){
    var nCorrespondingVal = jQuery("select[title='Regio'] > option:contains('+sRegio+')").val();
    jQuery("select[title='Regio']").val(nCorrespondingVal);
}
```

The line should populate the value from the url query in an DropDown menu

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) {
          url = window.location.href;
        }
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var sRegio = "Regio "+getParameterByName('regio');
    //output = Regio Zuid

    function fnSelectDropDownValue(){
    var nCorrespondingVal = jQuery("select[title='Regio'] > option:contains('+sRegio+')").val();
        jQuery("select[title='Regio']").val(nCorrespondingVal);
    }

    });
```

Comment: You haven't called the `fnSelectDropDownValue` function in your code. 
`jQuery("select[title='Regio']").val(nCorrespondingVal);` isn't working on your console due to scope issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

put your function outside **jQuery(document).ready(function () {});** block

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    var sRegio = "Regio " + getParameterByName('regio');
});
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
        url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
function fnSelectDropDownValue() {
    var nCorrespondingVal = jQuery("select[title='Regio'] > option:contains('+sRegio+')").val();
    jQuery("select[title='Regio']").val(nCorrespondingVal);
}
```